# Median of unknown distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_8$ be iid random variables with unknown probability density function $f$. Denote by $Y_1, Y_2, \ldots, Y_8$ their order statistics: realizations of $X_i$ sorted in increasing order. What is the probability that $Y_2 \le m \le Y_7$, where $m$ denotes median of our (unknown) distribution?

I've calculated the answer for few popular distributions, like: uniform, binomial or exponential and the answer seems to be

$$\frac{119}{128}.$$

But why?

Comment: The binomial has nothing to do with this. It is discrete, and with a discrete distribution you shouldn't expect any "universal" property like this one. For example, with a (nontrivial) Bernoulli(p) distribution, any reasonable "median" is strictly between $0$ and $1$, so that $P(Y_2 \leq m \leq Y_7)={8 \choose 2}^2 p^2 (1-p)^2$, which depends nontrivially on $p$.

Comment: As for the continuous case, look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#The_joint_distribution_of_the_order_statistics_of_an_absolutely_continuous_distribution

Comment: I think to boil this down into your case, you will want to do the integral $\int_{-\infty}^m \int_m^\infty f_{Y_2,Y_7}(x,y) dy dx$ by substituting $u=F^{-1}(x),v=F^{-1}(y)$, where $F^{-1}$ denotes the quantile function. I think this will probably answer your question (again in the continuous regime). Part of what helps there is that in the continuous regime the quantile function is a right inverse, i.e. $F(F^{-1}(x))=x$; this is not true in the discrete regime. So all those CDFs turn into $x$s and $y$s under this substitution, and also the limits turn into $\int_0^{1/2} \int_{1/2}^1$.

Comment: Er, I think I actually meant $u=F(x),v=F(y)$. Close enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the special case of the uniform distribution on $(0,1)$, the joint distribution of the $j$th and $k$th order statistics can be obtained by combinatoric considerations: for $(Y_j,Y_k)$ to fall in a given rectangle $[x,x+dx] \times [y,y+dy]$ (where $j \leq k$ and $x \leq y$), you need $j-1$ variables in $[0,x]$, $1$ in $[x,x+dx]$, $k-1-j$ in $[x+dx,y]$, and $n-k$ in $[y,1]$. So the joint pdf winds up being:

$$f_{Y_j,Y_k}(x,y)=\frac{n!}{(j-1)!(k-j-1)!(n-k)!} x^{j-1} (y-x)^{k-j-1} (1-y)^{n-k}$$

for $0 \leq x \leq y \leq 1$ and zero elsewhere. You can interpret the big aggregate of factorials as either a normalization constant or as the number of ways to permute the variables to obtain such a configuration. For the case of the uniform distribution you need to integrate this over $[0,1/2] \times [1/2,1]$. For other continuous distributions, you get a similar integral involving the CDF, which can be converted into this one by substituting $u=F(x),v=F(y)$. So your case boils down to

$$\int_0^{1/2} \int_{1/2}^1 \frac{8!}{1! 4! 1!} x^1 (y-x)^4 (1-y)^1 dy dx = \frac{119}{128}.$$

For non-continuous distributions, even if there is a well-defined median, you won't have any universal result like you do in the continuous case.